# Applying a foreach loop over combinations of different values

Tags: r

I have some data I want to apply some sort of monte carlo simulation over. I have different combinations of `n` and `k` and I want to run the forloop over these different combinations. The below code works for single values of `n` and `k`

Code:

```
formula <- as.formula(predictions ~ age + daysInHospital)
result <- glm(formula = formula, data = df, family = binomial)

Tdays = 100 # number of days
k = 6 # k new people coming to the hospital each day - randomly taken from the df
N = 89 # number of available beds each day
# objective: decide who stays in the hospital and who is released based on the probabilities
# policy: keep in the hospital the N patients with the highest prob of mortality
# each day, we have a cut-off and patients with at least this prob of mortality will stay in hospital for another day
# i.e. newcomers will have 0 days in hospital but everybody else will have + 1 day in hospital
MCtot = 5 # total number of monte carlos simulations to run

set.seed(0)
out <- data.frame()

for(indMC in 1:MCtot){
  print(paste("Current MC run: ", indMC, "out of: ", MCtot ))
  # initial patients in hospital for this MC loop
  patients = df %>% 
    sample_n(N)
  
  for(t in 1:Tdays){
    # take newcomers, with different prob and with daysInHospital=0
    newcomers = df %>% 
      sample_n(k) %>% 
      mutate(
        daysInHospital = 0 # since these are the newcommers they will have 0 days in hospital
      )
    
    # apply policy: 'keep the N patients with highest prob'
    # make a pool with newcomers and patients
    aux1 = patients
    aux1 = rbind(aux1, newcomers, fill = TRUE)
    # make predictions at period t,
    aux1$t_pred = predict(result, aux1, type = "response")
    # take the N-th highest
    cut_off <- aux1 %>% 
      arrange(desc(t_pred)) %>% 
      slice(N) %>% 
      pull(t_pred)
    # all patients with prob >= cut_off will stay in hospital one more day
    patients <- aux1 %>% 
      filter(t_pred >= cut_off)
    
    avg_prob <- patients %>% 
      summarise(
        avg_prob = mean(t_pred)
      ) %>% 
      pull(avg_prob)
    
    # remove auxiliar
    aux1 <- NULL
    # store information of current day
    aux1 <- data.frame(
      MCrun = indMC,
      period = t,
      cut_off = cut_off,
      avg_prob = avg_prob,
      n = N,
      k = k
    )
    out <- rbind(out, aux1)
    # update daysinHospital in patients and remove auxiliar
    
    # update daysinHospital in patients
    patients <- patients %>% 
      mutate(
        daysInHospital + 1
      )
  }
}
```

Now I want to generate random combinations of `n` and `k` and apply the same forloop storing the results in `out`.

I try to wrap the forloop inside a foreach loop but I don't get the correct output and it returns and error.

Output:

```
[1] "Current k:  4 Current n:  90"
[1] "Current MC run:  1 out of:  5"
[1] "Current MC run:  2 out of:  5"
[1] "Current MC run:  3 out of:  5"
[1] "Current MC run:  4 out of:  5"
[1] "Current MC run:  5 out of:  5"
[1] "Current k:  96 Current n:  21"
[1] "Current MC run:  1 out of:  5"
[1] "Current k:  57 Current n:  4"
[1] "Current MC run:  1 out of:  5"
[1] "Current MC run:  2 out of:  5"
[1] "Current MC run:  3 out of:  5"
[1] "Current MC run:  4 out of:  5"
[1] "Current MC run:  5 out of:  5"
Error in { : 
  task 2 failed - "`size` must be less or equal than 94 (size of data), set `replace` = TRUE to use sampling with replacement."
```

Code (which breaks)

```
formula <- as.formula(predictions ~ age + daysInHospital)
result <- glm(formula = formula, data = df, family = binomial)

Tdays = 100 # number of days

K = floor(runif(3, min = 0, max = 100))
N = floor(runif(3, min = 0, max = 100))

MCtot = 5 # total number of monte carlos simulations to run

set.seed(0)
out <- data.frame()



foreach(k = K, n = N) %do% {
  print(paste("Current k: ", k, "Current n: ", n))
  for(indMC in 1:MCtot){
    print(paste("Current MC run: ", indMC, "out of: ", MCtot ))
    # initial patients in hospital for this MC loop
    patients = df %>% 
      sample_n(n)                                 # changed n here (from upper to lowercase)
    
    for(t in 1:Tdays){
      # take newcomers, with different prob and with daysInHospital=0
      newcomers = df %>% 
        sample_n(k) %>% 
        mutate(
          daysInHospital = 0 # since these are the newcommers they will have 0 days in hospital
        )
      
      # apply policy: 'keep the N patients with highest prob'
      # make a pool with newcomers and patients
      aux1 = patients
      aux1 = rbind(aux1, newcomers, fill = TRUE)
      # make predictions at period t,
      aux1$t_pred = predict(result, aux1, type = "response")
      # take the N-th highest
      cut_off <- aux1 %>% 
        arrange(desc(t_pred)) %>% 
        slice(n) %>%                                  # changed n here (from upper to lowercase) 
        pull(t_pred)
      # all patients with prob >= cut_off will stay in hospital one more day
      patients <- aux1 %>% 
        filter(t_pred >= cut_off)
      
      avg_prob <- patients %>% 
        summarise(
          avg_prob = mean(t_pred)
        ) %>% 
        pull(avg_prob)
      
      # remove auxiliar
      aux1 <- NULL
      # store information of current day
      aux1 <- data.frame(
        MCrun = indMC,
        period = t,
        cut_off = cut_off,
        avg_prob = avg_prob,
        n = n,                                  # changed n here (from upper to lowercase)
        k = k
      )
      out <- rbind(out, aux1)
      # update daysinHospital in patients and remove auxiliar
      
      # update daysinHospital in patients
      patients <- patients %>% 
        mutate(
          daysInHospital + 1
        )
    }
  }
}
```

Any hints on how I can apply the forloop for different combinations on `n` and `k`.

Additionally, I tried to recreate the forloop but using functions - I can put the code for the functions if needed - its incomplete since I could not update the `daysInHospital` variable at each iteration `patients <- patients %>% mutate(daysInHospital + 1)`

Packages:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(foreach)
```

Data:

```
    df <- structure(list(predictions = c(0.456592172384262, 0.311251223087311, 
0.322826206684113, 0.320436120033264, 0.420515507459641, 0.311251223087311, 
0.340740621089935, 0.344267100095749, 0.33494707942009, 0.316163510084152, 
0.439167380332947, 0.45088067650795, 0.348440110683441, 0.348440110683441, 
0.364672362804413, 0.311251223087311, 0.311251223087311, 0.31931933760643, 
0.363355785608292, 0.311251223087311, 0.320436120033264, 0.419657677412033, 
0.541518926620483, 0.597665846347809, 0.320436120033264, 0.31931933760643, 
0.311251223087311, 0.311251223087311, 0.311251223087311, 0.317184776067734, 
0.338966459035873, 0.375375002622604, 0.367403119802475, 0.320436120033264, 
0.320436120033264, 0.488717943429947, 0.311251223087311, 0.311251223087311, 
0.427019357681274, 0.320436120033264, 0.316163510084152, 0.408030122518539, 
0.676600515842438, 0.65798020362854, 0.663134813308716, 0.405547618865967, 
0.666221380233765, 0.584704995155334, 0.519161760807037, 0.679032862186432, 
0.663134813308716, 0.493949443101883, 0.520084738731384, 0.519354522228241, 
0.673770666122437, 0.541518926620483, 0.592103779315948, 0.320436120033264, 
0.631685137748718, 0.663134813308716, 0.673770666122437, 0.573903799057007, 
0.38736030459404, 0.475033223628998, 0.663134813308716, 0.608104407787323, 
0.679032862186432, 0.657724738121033, 0.596750199794769, 0.634064376354218, 
0.32214692234993, 0.679032862186432, 0.609701991081238, 0.663134813308716, 
0.663134813308716, 0.663134813308716, 0.679032862186432, 0.666221380233765, 
0.526929080486298, 0.663134813308716, 0.663134813308716, 0.663134813308716, 
0.357654452323914, 0.539961099624634, 0.679032862186432, 0.553646564483643, 
0.611478388309479, 0.639116942882538, 0.663134813308716, 0.663134813308716, 
0.679032862186432, 0.632321059703827, 0.679032862186432, 0.519354522228241
), age = c(61L, 29L, 32L, 68L, 66L, 39L, 36L, 39L, 30L, 33L, 
75L, 44L, 63L, 66L, 67L, 31L, 52L, 45L, 38L, 33L, 63L, 46L, 69L, 
62L, 64L, 33L, 44L, 53L, 57L, 60L, 42L, 67L, 36L, 68L, 66L, 70L, 
42L, 39L, 43L, 64L, 59L, 34L, 73L, 65L, 79L, 19L, 51L, 65L, 70L, 
71L, 64L, 87L, 64L, 69L, 74L, 80L, 65L, 65L, 77L, 75L, 77L, 58L, 
54L, 57L, 81L, 53L, 85L, 73L, 62L, 57L, 52L, 82L, 71L, 78L, 74L, 
91L, 67L, 62L, 80L, 63L, 82L, 64L, 59L, 60L, 68L, 62L, 65L, 82L, 
76L, 68L, 71L, 62L, 74L, 63L), daysInHospital = c(15L, 17L, 14L, 
12L, 19L, 15L, 17L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 16L, 15L, 16L, 19L, 20L, 18L, 
15L, 17L, 14L, 12L, 12L, 21L, 13L, 11L, 13L, 16L, 15L, 18L, 18L, 
16L, 15L, 18L, 17L, 9L, 8L, 15L, 19L, 15L, 29L, 5L, 5L, 0L, 7L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 29L, 14L, 7L, 4L, 9L, 18L, 10L, 9L, 13L, 14L, 
5L, 5L, 9L, 5L, 6L, 13L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 8L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 
2L, 4L, 9L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 28L, 9L, 6L, 6L, 17L, 11L, 2L, 29L, 29L, 
2L, 1L, 0L, 5L, 10L, 0L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, -94L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

EDIT:

Just running anothe random sample of `N` and `K` seems to work:

```
[1] "Current k:  10 Current n:  80"
[1] "Current MC run:  1 out of:  5"
[1] "Current MC run:  2 out of:  5"
[1] "Current MC run:  3 out of:  5"
[1] "Current MC run:  4 out of:  5"
[1] "Current MC run:  5 out of:  5"
[1] "Current k:  42 Current n:  91"
[1] "Current MC run:  1 out of:  5"
[1] "Current MC run:  2 out of:  5"
[1] "Current MC run:  3 out of:  5"
[1] "Current MC run:  4 out of:  5"
[1] "Current MC run:  5 out of:  5"
[1] "Current k:  17 Current n:  27"
[1] "Current MC run:  1 out of:  5"
[1] "Current MC run:  2 out of:  5"
[1] "Current MC run:  3 out of:  5"
[1] "Current MC run:  4 out of:  5"
[1] "Current MC run:  5 out of:  5"
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
NULL
```

I am not sure why I get 3 NULLs at the end however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting an error in the first example is because you are sampling a value of `k` greater than the rows of `df` (`k = 96`). So when you use this value of `k` to sample the rows of `df` it gives an error. This error does not occur in your second example, because all values of `k` and `n` are less than `94`.

You have two solutions for this (not sure which one is better in your application).

- Set `replace = TRUE` in the `sample_n` functions. This way you will be sampling with replacement (but note that there could be repeated values).
- When creating the values of `K` and `N`, set an upper bound of 94 or less in the `runif` function.

Note that this could also be an issue when you use `slice(n)`. So probably the second solution could be better.

The reason you get the 3 `NULL` values in the end of the second example is because `foreach` is a function that returns the value of the last executed command. In your case, the last executed command is inside a `for` loop and it is not returned. So `foreach` returns NULL. To hide these return values, you can put the return value of `foreach` into a dummy variable.

```
dummy.variable <- foreach(k = K, n = N) %do% {
  print(paste("Current k: ", k, "Current n: ", n))
  for(indMC in 1:MCtot){
    print(paste("Current MC run: ", indMC, "out of: ", MCtot ))
  }
}
```

Just to illustrate the behaviour of `foreach`. An example where the last command returns 1.

```
foreach(k = K, n = N) %do% {
  print(paste("Current k: ", k, "Current n: ", n))
  for(indMC in 1:MCtot){
    print(paste("Current MC run: ", indMC, "out of: ", MCtot ))
  }
  1
}

[1] "Current k:  31 Current n:  42"
[1] "Current MC run:  1 out of:  5"
[1] "Current MC run:  2 out of:  5"
[1] "Current MC run:  3 out of:  5"
[1] "Current MC run:  4 out of:  5"
[1] "Current MC run:  5 out of:  5"
[1] "Current k:  61 Current n:  74"
[1] "Current MC run:  1 out of:  5"
[1] "Current MC run:  2 out of:  5"
[1] "Current MC run:  3 out of:  5"
[1] "Current MC run:  4 out of:  5"
[1] "Current MC run:  5 out of:  5"
[1] "Current k:  58 Current n:  81"
[1] "Current MC run:  1 out of:  5"
[1] "Current MC run:  2 out of:  5"
[1] "Current MC run:  3 out of:  5"
[1] "Current MC run:  4 out of:  5"
[1] "Current MC run:  5 out of:  5"
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 1

[[3]]
[1] 1
```

If that `1` value were inside the inner `for` loop, it would return `NULL`.